# Efficiently Building a Price Table from a MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to display a table of room prices like this:
[image]

There are 18 date columns and they won't all be the same tariff. Amongst the 18 columns there could be anything between 1 and 6 different tariffs. For this reason I have a tariff and a price table in my database.

```
tariff:     tariff_id     room_id

price:      tariff_id     double_weekday     single_weekday     double weekend     single_weekend     extrabed
```

Then there is a dates table:

```
dates:     date     tariff_id    hotel_id     + some more fields
```

My problem is finding the best way to construct my MySql queries in an efficient way. Obviously I don't want to run a query for every cell in the table.

I have started by finding the tariffs that are applicable to the date range being displayed.

```
$query_tariff = "SELECT tariff_id, date FROM dates WHERE (date BETWEEN '$firstdate' AND '$lastdate') AND hotel_id = '$hid'";
```

Then I can readily reduce that result to the unique values of tariff_id.

Then I have a query to get all the prices corresponding to each if the tariffs:

```
while ($row_tariff = mysql_fetch_assoc($tariff)) {
$tariff_id = $row_tariff['tariff_id'];
$query_price = "SELECT * FROM price WHERE tariff_id = '$tariff_id'";
}
```

My problem comes at the next stage. As I write each  across a row, how do I know which price to use? I have a feeling this may require pivot-table, but I have done some reading on this and got completely lost. Or perhaps the solution lies in the use of arrays, which I stand a slightly better chance of being able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

the simple option would be to break it down to something like (pseudo-code)

```
foreach room_type
    // write row start & header
    foreach interested_date
        // write cell for the best rate/availability on this interested_date, for this room_type
    next
    // write row end
next
```

Now, you *could* loop on the results of two queries, or you could combine into a single monster query, with appropriate logic to write a new row end/start & header

Comment: The problem is what happens inside "foreach interested date". It seems like I would have to have a query there to get the price information. So if there are six room types, that would be 6 x 18 = 108 queries just to display the table once.

Comment: or query for all rates for that room type. Personally, I'd design the price table to be one rate, for one day, for one room type. You could then query, with the relevant joins where the availability date is between the start date and end date of your search.